# iPhone as Pendrive

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to create an application which makes iPhone act as a pendrive to share all types of files.

Initially i have some files(jpg, png, pdf, zip) in a folder in my mac. I need to display those files in a table view in the simulator. I am using NSMutableArray to hold those files. But i dont know how to display that mutable array to the table view.

Please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: You should be aware that the iPhone will not show up as a USB mass storage device, and there isn't a way to make it do so on a non-jailbroken device.  If you're using iTunes file sharing support, you can add and remove files only within iTunes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically there are 3 of the UITableViewDataSource methods you need

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  This is where you can put data into the cell i.e: "cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]"
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
  Tells the tableview the sections in the table i.e 1
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  Number of rows in that section - i.e: [array count];

Comment: Remember in the .h file after the class name put: <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> like this:

"@interface CLASS_NAME : EXTENDS <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {"

Comment: ... and on the tableview IBOutlet or Object do the following - UITABLEVIEW_OBJECT_VARIABLE.delegate= self and UITABLEVIEW_OBJECT_VARIABLE.dataSource = self;

Comment: Also checkout:  http://goo.gl/p2eXt - Apple Documentation on Datasource and http://goo.gl/hCGpF - Apple Documentation on Delegate methods

Comment: Finally take a look at Apple's sample code (TableView Suite) which has a lot of examples using a tableview: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007318

Comment: If I helped please can you mark the answer as resolved - tick the box and click the up arrow ;O) - Thanks James